# DNS setting randomly changes

Tags: networking, dns, netplan

## Update

Seemingly went away on it's own. Please close.

## The problem

My Custom DNS-Server is randomly not queried anymore.

## The Setup

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have my own DNS server in my network. I set up my dhcp server to set up that DNS server for the network. Before I had set up my DNS server explicitly, but now I am visiting two wifi access points and the second one doesn't have that DNS server.
Now I have deleted the `nameservers` section from my netplan yaml file, because I can't seem to set it on a per AP basis.
After a reconnect everything works fine for a while, but then suddenly the DNS server doesn't answer anymore for anything in my lan, but public stuff like google works fine.
When I reconnect then, it works again for a while, and then seemingly randomly stops.

Running `dig` with the dns server explicitly works fine.
I am confused, dig says the response comes from the systemd-resolved resolver on 127.0.0.53. However the output of `systemd-resolved --status` reports the correct dns server settings for my interface.

```
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 4 (tun0)
<OpenVPN not in use>

Link 3 (wlp1s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.5
                      <ipv6>
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      lan

Link 2 (enp2s0)
<not in use>
```

Setting the DNS IP for the interface in netplan via

```
nameservers:
  addressess: [my.local.dns.server]
  search: [lan]
```

works fine, but again I can't do that anymore because i visit multiple access points and a configuration per access point seems impossible at the moment.
Setting the DNS server in network manager on it's own connection works fine, also.

I find this rather frustrating and want to know what DNS server I am using and why my own one isn't used anymore at random, and also why it comes back at random. I disabled DHCP on my fritzbox, it acts as a DNS server, but shouldn't be used (my own dns server uses it after 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8).

## My configuration:

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
# [comment block about this being systemd-dnsresolv stub]
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search lan
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 <myhostname>.lan <myhostname>

::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

## Edit

I had a look with wireshark when I ran `dig`. DNS queries were sent out to an ipv6 address, not my local dns server. The IPv6 Address was that of my router. Why is that?

## Edit2

My current netplan config:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      access-points:
        "SSID1":
          password: ****
        "SSID2":
          password: ****
```